# I accidentally deleted the Release.xcconfig file in my project, how do I recreate it?

Tags: xcode

I've been looking online for the differences between the Debug.xcconfig file and the Release.xcconfig file and haven't been able to find any. Like the title states, I accidentally deleted my Release config file and I'm worried that there might be some build settings that are necessary when archiving my app.

Can anyone help me understand what I need to change in a duplication of a debug configuration, in order to make it to the standard release build?

Comment: Just restore the deleted file from source control (git) or from your Time Machine backup.

Comment: @rmaddy I don't see it at all in terminal or the embedded Xcode git view.